# creating a wcf program to fetch data from Oracle database (12c) and will be hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, connection-string, oracle12c

I am using System.Data.OracleClient which has been deprecated. Any suggestion will be appreciated on how and what should I do to replace System.Data.OracleClient. 
I have tried to Add Oracle.DataAccess by going to solution explorer , add reference. Oracle.DataAccess is not shoiwing in my avaialble options (I do not have the .NET tab).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give me examples or a link to look into if any suggestion provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) from Oracle?

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet)

> The types in System.Data.OracleClient are deprecated. The types remain
>   supported in the current version of.NET Framework but will be removed
>   in a future release. Microsoft recommends that you use a third-party
>   Oracle provider.

You could install this library as a NuGet package as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui)
[image]

Comment: Oracle Data Provider for .NET  = Oracle.DataAccess  . Check this link : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/code-154692.html

Comment: @user5511576, sorry my bad - so you are not seeing the .NET tab, but have you installed the ODP.NET?

Comment: that's correct! :(

Comment: @user5511576, have you tried installing it via NuGet? Please see my updated answer

Comment: no, I have not. I am giving it a try . Hopefully I'll be all set. Fingers crossed. Will update you tomorrow about how it goes. Thanks bunch!\

Comment: @user5511576, give it a shot, good luck!

Comment: Hi @user5511576, how did it go? Is your problem solved? If everything worked out, please mark this as the correct answer. Best regards!

Comment: Hi ironstone13, I ended up using Visual Studio 2015, and I was able to use my application correctly. I used your suggested method to add the Oracle.DataAccess. However, it is a unmanaged driver and was not working properly. Found a forum where they suggested using an older version of visual Studio, and that worked for me !Thanks for your input though. I did mark your answer as the correct one since I was able to add it.